# Python converting time with print suggestion

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-requests, jupyter

Semantic Error: How do I get "am" instead of "pm" what am I doing wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
m2="23:00:00"

in_time = datetime.strptime(m2, "%H:%M:%S")
out_time = datetime.strftime(in_time, "%I:%M:%S %p")

print(out_time)

if out_time < "12:00:00" :
    print('Good morning.')
elif "12:00:00" <= out_time < "04:00:00":
    print('Good afternoon.')
else :
    print('Good evening.')
```

Answer (which is wrong):

> 11:00:00 PM Good morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to get AM you need a time to start that is between 00:00 and 11:59 as in the 24 hour clock you are PM after 12:00.

The other problem is that you are converting a time to a string in a format that has 2 of each hour in there and then comparing the string to determine what to print. Try comparing times, which can be generated with the constructor rather than `strptime`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime

in_time = dateteime.time(11, 15) # Time in H:M 11:15 AM
if in_time < datetime.time(12):  # Before Noon
    goodbit = "morning"
elif in_time < datetime.time(16):  # Before 4 PM (we already know > 12:00)
    goodbit = "afternoon"
else:  # (After 16:00)
    goodbit = "evening"
print("{} Good {}".format(in_time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"), goodbit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the time strings.  Instead you should compare the [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#module-time) values like:

#### Code:

```
def time_of_day_msg(in_time):
    if in_time < dt.time(hour=12):
        return 'Good morning.'
    elif in_time < dt.time(hour=16):
        return 'Good afternoon.'
    else:
        return 'Good evening.'
```

#### Test Code:

```
import datetime as dt
for time in ("1:00:00", "13:00:00", "23:00:00"):
    print(time, time_of_day_msg(
        dt.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S").time()))
```

#### Results:

```
1:00:00 Good morning.
13:00:00 Good afternoon.
23:00:00 Good evening.
```